# How to hide highchart if checkbox is unchecked?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor, highcharts

```
$("#searchButton").click(function () {
    getData();
});

function getData() {
    //alert('button clicked');
    var dateFrom = $('#datetimepickerFrom').val();
    var dateTo = $('#datetimepickerTo').val();

    var id = $('#ddlSite').val();
    Module.loader('show');
    $("#graphId").empty();
    //zatim za graf
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ROOT + "Test/GetGraph",
        data: { validFrom: dateFrom, validTo: dateTo, deviceId: id },
        cache: false,
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var brUredjaja = data.length;
            //console.log('broj izabranih stanica je : ' + brojIzabranihStanica);
            for (i = 0; i < brUredjaja; i++) {
                {
                    var brParametara = data[i].series.length;

                    if ((brParametara > 1) || (brUredjaja > 1)) {
                        for (j = 0; j < brParametara; j++) {
                            {
                                $("#graphId").append("<div class='graphReport col-md-6' id = div" + i + "dev" + j + "></div>");
                                $('#checkbox').append('<input type="checkbox" checked id="myCheckbox" /*value="' + series[j].name + '"*//>' + data[i].series[j].name);
                                InitGraph(data[i].dates, data[i].series[j].data, "div" + i + "dev" + j, data[i].series[j].name, data[i].deviceName);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (j = 0; j < brParametara; j++) {
                            {
                                $("#graphId").append("<div class='graphReport col-md-12' id = div" + i + "dev" + j + "></div>");
                                $('#checkbox').append('<input type="checkbox" checked id="myCheckbox" />' + data[i].series[j].name);
                                InitGraph(data[i].dates, data[i].series[j].data, "div" + i + "dev" + j, data[i].series[j].name, data[i].deviceName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Module.loader('hide');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            Module.loader('hide');
            if (xhr.status === 403) {
                window.location = ROOT + 'Dashboard/Main/';
            }
        }
    })
}


function InitGraph(times, seriesVal, id, name, device) {
    categories = [];
    niz = [];
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: true
        }
    });

    $('#' + id).highcharts({
        tyraphIdpe: 'spline',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        title: {
            text: name
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: times
        },
        yAxis: {
            //min: 0,
            //max: 40,
            tickInterval: 10,
            title: {
                text: device
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.x + '<br/>' +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: name,
            data: seriesVal
        }],
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                connectNulls: true
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is my Javascript where, after click on Search button, highchart grpahs and comboboxes are rendered to the page.

This is my cshtml code:

```
@using EkoNET.Languages;
@model EkoNET.WebApp.Models.TestViewModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<div class="reportsDiv col-md-12 " style="padding-top:40px;">

    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10 visualisationDropdowns">

        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedId, Model.Sites, new { id = "ddlSite", @class = "form-control" })

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sites)

        <input class="form-control droneDateTimePicker" placeholder="@Resource.From" id="datetimepickerFrom" type="text">
        <input class="form-control droneDateTimePicker" placeholder="@Resource.To" id="datetimepickerTo" type="text">
        <input type="button" id="searchButton" class="specificImageButton btn btn-default" value="@Resource.search" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>

<div id="checkbox">

</div>

<div class="col-md-12 row" id="graphPlaceHolder" style="padding-top:20px">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10 visualisationDiv">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_GraphVis", Model);}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div id="messagediv" class="col-md-9"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>

<img id="backGroundImageId" src="" class="decorationImage">

@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Content/js/pages/TestScript.js"></script>
}
```

Intittialy every checkbox is checked and all graphs are visible...

So, the point is how to "connect" checkboxs with the highchart and how to hide certain hraph if user unchec some checkboxes?

I gues I have to give value of `#checkbox` in every iterattion in for loop in javascript

Answer (score 0):

I did it:
In javascript I added

```
function initGraphCheckBoxes() {
    $('.graphCb').on('change', function () {
        var graphName = $(this).attr('graph-name');
        $('div[graph-name="' + graphName + '"]').toggle();
    })
}
```

And in for loop changed

```
$("#graphId").append("<div class='graphReport col-md-6' id = div" + i + "dev" + j + "></div>");
$('#checkbox').append('<input type="checkbox" checked id="myCheckbox" /*value="' + series[j].name + '"*//>' + data[i].series[j].name);
```

to

```
$("#graphId").append("<div class='graphReport col-md-6' id = div" + i + "dev" + j + " graph-name='" + data[i].series[j].name +"'></div>");
$('#checkbox').append('<input type="checkbox" checked class="graphCb" graph-name="' + data[i].series[j].name +'" />' + data[i].series[j].name);
```